# sostats - Stack Overflow latest metrics and charts

Tags: app, users, website, posts, statistics

### About

I wondered how many questions, answers or comments are being posted on Stack Overflow every day. How many users get registered? How does it depend on the day of the week? When are users most active? The Stack Exchange API gives me particular numbers but I wanted to see them together. So I've built [sostats](http://sostats.github.io/) - Stack Overflow statistics, a website that visualizes these numbers.

### Screenshots

#### Dashboard

- total number of questions, answers, comments and users
- number of questions, answers, comments and new users in the last hour
- updated every minute

[image: sostats dashboard screenshot]

#### Last 24h

- charts presenting number of questions, answers, comments and new users per hour

[image: sostats last 24 hours charts screenshot]

#### Last 30 days

- charts presenting number of questions, answers, comments and new users per day

[image: sostats last 30 days charts screenshot]

### Contact

Łukasz Wiktor

- email: lukasz.wiktor@gmail.com
- twitter: [@LukaszWiktor](https://twitter.com/LukaszWiktor)

### Code

https://github.com/sostats/sostats.github.io